# Silverlight Refresh Data in Combo Box

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a Data Grid that contains user selections on a SL form.  From time to time, there are updates to the data in the Data Grid every 10 seconds.  Is there a way to constantly refresh the data once the page has loaded?  I found something called a DispatcherTimer that can run every 10 seconds (for example) but I'm not sure if I'm thinking this through correctly.

Does anyone know if this something like this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Data binding should take care of this all for you automatically, assuming you are using `ObservableCollection<T>` for the `ItemsSource` and `INotifyPropertyChanged` for the data item  `<T>` properties.